# sparkR hdfs error - Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4

Tags: r, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I have installed sparkR in Ubuntu to support Hadoop version 2.4.0, following the instructions  [here](https://parambirs.wordpress.com/2014/05/20/running-spark-1-0-0-snapshot-on-hadoopyarn-2-4-0/).

I can see that the assembly JAR for Spark with Hadoop 2.4.0 and YARN support is created at the following location `./assembly/target/scala-2.10/spark-assembly-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.4.0.jar`.

The R code below to read file from local works fine:

```r
library(SparkR)
sc <- sparkR.init("local[2]", "SparkR", "/usr/local/spark",
              list(spark.executor.memory="1g"))
lines <- textFile(sc, "//home//manohar//text.txt")
```

However, I get error when trying to read the file from hdfs.

```
library(SparkR)
sc <- sparkR.init()
lines <- textFile(sc, "hdfs://localhost:9000//in//text.txt")
```

Error:

```
Error in .jcall(getJRDD(rdd), "Ljava/util/List;", "collect") : 
  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4
```

Not sure where I'm doing wrong. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The link you gave doesnt have any SparkR installation steps. According to sparkR readme, SparkR by default links to Hadoop 1.0.4. To use SparkR with other Hadoop versions, you will need to rebuild SparkR with the same version that [Spark is linked to]
    `SPARK_HADOOP_VERSION=2.4.0 ./install-dev.sh`

Comment: I have rebuilt the sparkR with the hadoop version 2.4.0 and the proof is that I see hadoop YARN support jar file at ~./assembly/target/scala-2.10/spark-assembly-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.4.0.jar~. Even after that I was getting the error posted in question. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.